# TCP Connection readline error/incorrect reading

Tags: java, tcp

What is happenning:

```
Main server -> String("isalive") => Other server
Other server -> String("alive") => Main server
```

Ports and stuff are configured (both servers are dedicated machines)

And code. The place where stuff seem to break is (i added debug messages....)

```
reader.readLine();
```

Main server code:

```
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(key, 6789);
        if(clientSocket.isConnected() && !clientSocket.isClosed()){
            String in;

            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());   
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));  
            outToServer.writeBytes(isalive);   
            outToServer.flush();
            //it wont go pass this one 
            in = inFromServer.readLine();   

            if(in.equals("alive")){
                if(!Data.hosts.get(key)){
                    Data.hosts.put(key, true);

                }
            }

            outToServer.close();
            inFromServer.close();
            clientSocket.close();
```

It wont go pass this one because it will stop at the other server.

Code:

```
Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();      
         BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));            
         DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());    
         //stuck here
         rec = inFromClient.readLine();    
         if(rec.equals("isalive")){
             outToClient.writeBytes("alive");    
         }

         inFromClient.close();

         outToClient.flush();
         outToClient.close();

         connectionSocket.close();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually sending a line anywhere ? i.e. a string ending with a \n

Comment: And don't use a `DataOutputStream` if your intention is sending strings. Use `PrintWriter` and `println`.

Comment: 1) it worked with \n 
2) Ill keep that in mind. I may send a single byte. I am worried because they may decompile it and it is going to be obfuscated anyway. Shall I send a byte?

Comment: __"Shall I send a byte?"__ - depends on what the requirement is. Maybe you'll have to make up a protocol or chose a well-known one ... We don't know all of your requirements and constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You should not combine DataOutputStream and BufferedReader.
Consider using [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) instead and specify character encodings as well (to be safe).

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

writer.println("Hello.");
writer.flush();
reader.readLine();
```